# How to install PhpUnit for WAMP now that PEAR method is no longer possible?

Tags: php, windows, phpunit, wampserver

All the instructions are about the [PEAR method which is now deprecated](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method).

So how do we install it to be able to run phpUnit from command line with WAMP?

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html - windows section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

install with composer - windows section.

Comment: I accept this answer, thanks for the pointer. See my answer for additional info.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, Peter Popelyshko found the solution. It is [documented under the windows section](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html).

I made a bit it simpler:

1) Copied the [phpunit.phar](https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar) file to the php directory `eg. c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\`, as the php dir was already in my PATH environment

2) in the same dir run the following command from command line:
`echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd` **OR** manually create a phpunit.cmd file with the following content: `@php "%~dp0phpunit.phar %*`

3) open a new command line and test with: `phpunit --version`

Should return `PHPUnit x.y.z by Sebastian Bergmann.`